# Content Types Error

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.8 and I has an app runing on this perfectly fine. But now I migrated the whole database and whenever I try to access a record in the admin I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/mitglieder/mitglied/22/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 583, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/utils/decorators.py", line 105, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 52, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 206, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1456, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/utils/decorators.py", line 105, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/db/transaction.py", line 394, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1450, in changeform_view
    return self.render_change_form(request, context, add=add, change=not add, obj=obj, form_url=form_url)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1088, in render_change_form
    'content_type_id': get_content_type_for_model(self.model).pk,
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 63, in get_content_type_for_model
    return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj, for_concrete_model=False)
  File "/home/franzritt/django-club41/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 58, in get_for_model
    " is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually."
RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.
```

I had started the project with 1.7 but I had moved to 1.8 and the one app was running without problems. However, I had not migrated the whole project before. What I can see from the migration history is that this migration did a migration on the auth app. But even if I migrate back before this I get the same error.

I had this or a similar error before when switching to 1.8 but it is not the issue with the name field. And I am not able to delete the django_content_types table in the database because auth is linked to this table. Can I somehow solve this?

Comment: I just noticed that there seems to be an issue with the django version it is running on. It seems to be still 1.7. Will upgrade and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

So after making sure that the dev-server and the production server were running at Django 1.8 everything worked well. I had some confusion in the environment paths of the start scripts.